# Как разместить в одном активити 2 кнопки ToggleButton

Tags: java, android, android-button

Как добавить в активити еще один слушатель `ToggleButton` для второй кнопки? 
 Вот как я использую одну кнопку (к сожалению, в учебниках обычно приводят примеры на одну кнопку)

```
public class XXX extends ActionBarActivity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
ToggleButton tbutton1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_xxx);
        tbutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbutton1);
        }
        //...

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean tg1) {
        if (tg1) {
            // ...
}};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько способов, вот некоторые из них:

1. В каждый обработчик в качестве параметра приходит `view` для
   которого произошло данное событие. Следовательно у полученного
   `view` можно взять `id` и в зависимости от этого выполнить
   те или иные действия.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean tg1) {
       switch(buttonView.getId()) {

           case R.id.toggle1:
               //событие от первой кнопки, делаем А
               break;

           case R.id.toggle2:
               //событие от второй кнопки, делаем Б
               break;

           default:
               break;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Для каждой `view` создавать обработчик как экземпляр анонимного
   класса

   ```
   private OnCheckedChangeListener toggle1Listener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean tg1) {
           //делаем А
       }
   }

   private OnCheckedChangeListener toggle2Listener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean tg1) {
           //делаем Б
       }
   }

   //установка в методе onCreate()
   toggle1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggle1Listener);
   toggle2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggle2Listener);
   ```

**UPD:** забыл сказать что для второго случая нет необходимости реализовывать интерфейс `OnCheckedChangeListener` в `Activity`

Comment: спасибо огромное